# python can't import pip as well as modules that installed by pip

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, pip

The version and position of my python and pip is as below

[image]

But it failed to import pip using python

[image]

Also, when I try to run `pip install selenium`, it shows an error that no permission to operate the collected packages.

[image]

[image]

I tried to run  `chown -R $USER /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`, but it shows 'Operation not permitted'.

To summary,

1.python and pip is not in the same directory and pip cannot be imported by python.

2. pip install meet with a problem of no operation permission after module packages downloaded.

How can I fix the problems ? Are they caused by the different directories of installed python and pip ? Thanks for your opinion ~

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

use sudo along with command, it seems user which you are using do not have sufficient permission.

Comment: It shows the same using sudo. And today I run ' sudo pip install pymysql' . It still cannot be imported in python although installed successfully. Thus, I guess somewhere not connected between pip and python. But the solution is yet not found ~

Comment: do you have any other version of python installed on same system ?

type pip and press tab if it is showing something pip2.7 then use `sudo pip2.7 install selenium`